# Python print item in list gives lots of results

Tags: python, list, printing, items

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
#i have 2 lists
for x in a:
 for y in b:
  print x,' vs ',y
```

> Then i got
>
> 1 vs 4 , 1 vs 5, 1 vs 6
>   ,2 vs 4 ... and so on

I need only 3 results :-
1 vs 4
2 vs 5
3 vs 6

Mean 1st item on a with 1st item on b and 2nd with 2nd and 3rd with 3rd
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers are fine, another approach would be using enumerate.

```
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    print x," vs ", b[i]
```

This generates a zipped list of sorts, where each value is paired with its index value in the list. E.g. `enumerate([1, 2, 3]) => [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]`.

Comment: If the list is ordered and the index is a simple count, this is a cleaner and more pythonic solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
[print('{0} vs {1}'.format(x,y)) for (x,y) in zip(a, b)]
```

Zip will join your two lists into ((1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6))

Comment: Apart from the syntax error, this one doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]

for first, second in zip(a,b):
    print(first, ' vs ', second)
```

`zip` ties together the values of `a` and `b`. So the first element of `zip(a,b)` is `[1,4]`, the next element is `[2,5]` and so on.
Note that zip creates an iterator, so you can't directly access the elements via index (`zip(a,b)[1]` doesn't work).

Comment: But bro one more question :

Answer (score 0):

Try this brother:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]

for i, j in zip(x, y):
print i + " / " + j
```

It will give you:

```
1 / 4
2 / 5
3 / 6
```

Also check: ["for loop" with two variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648626/for-loop-with-two-variables)

Answer (score 0):

**Zip** would be prefect for your use case.

More about zip:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
for x in zip(a,b):
    print x[0],' vs ',x[1]
```

**Note:** If the size of your lists are different then zip stops at the smallest element

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone zip(a,b) and enumerate(a,b) both working well but if i have lists like a = [1,2,3,4] and b = [1,2,3] then zip(a,b) only working 1,1 2,2 3,3 and the 4th var is not visible and the enumerate method is working well but in the end gives error out of range :)