# How to use 2 index variable in a single for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

In `C` language we can use two index variable in a single `for` loop like below.

```
for (i = 0, j = 0; i < i_max && j < j_max; i++, j++)
```

Can some one tell how to do this in `Python` ?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648626/for-loop-with-two-variables#18648679).

Comment: Yes, I got it. With zip we can do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["for loop" with two variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648626/for-loop-with-two-variables)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `zip` we can achieve this.

```
>>> i_max = 5
>>> j_max = 7
>>> for i, j in zip(range(0, i_max), range(0, j_max)):
...     print str(i) + ", " + str(j)
...
0, 0
1, 1
2, 2
3, 3
4, 4
```

Comment: I would not agree. This does not account for different-sized lists, does it?

Comment: Good solution by @rashok . Works well for equal sized list. If you wanted a dataframe, you could create a tuple of (i, j) and append to a list. That list can be used to create a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

If the first answer does not suffice; to account for lists of different sizes, a possible option would be:

```
a = list(range(5))
b = list(range(15))
for i,j in zip(a+[None]*(len(b)-len(a)),b+[None]*(len(a)-len(b))):
    print(i,j)
```

Or if one wants to cycle around shorter list:

```
from itertools import cycle

for i,j in zip(range(5),cycle(range(2)):
    print(i,j)
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to do that is to iterate over a comprehensive list of lists.
For example, if you want to obtain something like

```
for r in range(1, 3):
    for c in range(5, 7):
        print(r, c)
```

which produces

```
# 1 5
# 1 6
# 2 5
# 2 6
```

is by using

```
for i, j in [[_i, _j] for _i in range(1, 3) for _j in range(5, 7)]:
    print(i, j)
```

Maybe, sometimes one more line is not so bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Python by using the syntax `for i,j in iterable:`. Of course in this case the iterable must return a pair of values. So for your example, you have to:

- define the list of values for `i` and for `j`
- build the iterable returning a pair of values from both lists: `zip()` is your friend in this case (if the lists have different sizes, it stops at the last element of the shortest one)
- use the syntax `for i,j in iterable:`

Here is an example:

```
i_max = 7
j_max = 9

i_values = range(i_max)
j_values = range(j_max)

for i,j in zip(i_values,j_values):
    print(i,j)
    # 0 0
    # 1 1
    # 2 2
    # 3 3
    # 4 4
    # 5 5
    # 6 6
```

Comment: same answer as provided by @rashok