# Using multiple variables in a for loop in Python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, python-2.x

I am trying to get a deeper understanding to how `for` loops for different data types in Python. The simplest way of using a for loop an iterating over an array is as

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    do_something(array[i])
```

I also know that I can

```
for i in array:
    do_something(i)
```

What I would like to know is what this does

```
for i, j in range(len(array)):
    # What is i and j here?
```

or

```
for i, j in array:
    # What is i and j in this case?
```

And what happens if I try using this same idea with `dict`ionaries or `tuples`?

Comment: `for i, j in range(len(array))` won't work

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga second example will work if `array` is an iterable of length-2 iterables.

Comment: *[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648626/for-loop-with-two-variables)* might help?

Comment: I would argue that the simplest way of iterating over a _list_ in Python is to omit indices altogether: `for i in array: do_something(i)`.

Comment: Note that this is generally referred to as unpacking and is not restricted to ``for`` loops. It is the same mechanism as used in explicit assignment, such as ``values = 1, 2, 3`` and ``a, b, c = values``.

Comment: If you try it with a tuple instead of a list, it does the exact same thing. If you try it with a dict instead of a list, it does the same thing, but with the keys of the dict (and, before Python 3.7, those are in an arbitrary order). More generally, with any iterable type, it iterates all of the elements of that value, and you can read the docs for that type to see what that means.

Comment: Yes, good point

Answer (score 34):

The simplest and best way is the second one, not the first one!

```
for i in array:
    do_something(i)
```

Never do this, it's needlessly complicating the code:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    do_something(array[i])
```

If you need the index in the array for some reason (usually you don't), then do this instead:

```
for i, element in enumerate(array):
    print("working with index", i)
    do_something(element)
```

This is just an error, you will get `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` when trying to unpack one integer into two names:

```
for i, j in range(len(array)):
    # What is i and j here?
```

This one might work, assumes the array is "two-dimensional":

```
for i, j in array:
    # What is i and j in this case?
```

An example of a two-dimensional array would be a list of pairs:

```
>>> for i, j in [(0, 1), ('a', 'b')]:
...     print('i:', i, 'j:', j)
...     
i: 0 j: 1
i: a j: b
```

*Note:* `['these', 'structures']` are called lists in Python, not arrays.

Comment: I wonder if the range concern is still valid since python3 (using iterators and stuff).

Comment: Yes, it's still valid all the same.

Answer (score 8):

Your third loop will not work as it will throw a `TypeError` for an `int` not being `iterable`. This is because you are trying to "`unpack`" the int that is the array's index into `i`, and `j` which is not possible. An example of unpacking is like so:

```
tup = (1,2)
a,b = tup
```

where you assign `a` to be the first value in the `tuple` and `b` to be the second. This is also useful when you may have a `function` return a tuple of values and you want to unpack them immediately when calling the function. Like,

```
train_X, train_Y, validate_X, validate_Y = make_data(data)
```

More common loop cases that I believe you are referring to is how to iterate over an arrays items and it's index.

```
for i, e in enumerate(array):
    ...
```

and

```
for k,v in d.items():  
    ...
```

when iterating over the items in a `dictionary`. Furthermore, if you have two lists, `l1` and `l2` you can iterate over both of the contents like so

```
for e1, e2 in zip(l1,l2):
    ...
```

Note that this will truncate the longer list in the case of unequal lengths while iterating. Or say that you have a lists of lists where the outer lists are of length `m` and the inner of length `n` and you would rather iterate over the elements in the inner lits grouped together by index. This is effectively iterating over the transpose of the matrix, you can use zip to perform this operation as well.

```
for inner_joined in zip(*matrix):  # will run m times
    # len(inner_joined) == m
    ...
```

Comment: @rahlf23 And maybe just an list of 2-tuples as points or something.

Answer (score 6):

Python's for loop is an iterator-based loop (that's why [bruno desthuilliers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51934046/5675325) says that it "works for all iterables (lists, tuples, sets, dicts, iterators, generators etc)". A string is also another common type of iterable).

Let's say you have a list of tuples. Using that nomenclature you shared, one can iterate through both the keys and values simultaneously. For instance:

```
tuple_list = [(1, "Countries, Cities and Villages"),(2,"Animals"),(3, "Objects")]

for k, v in tuple_list:
    print(k, v)
```

will give you the output:

```
1 Countries, Cities and Villages
2 Animals
3 Objects
```

If you use a dictionary, you'll also gonna be able to do this. The difference here is the need for .items()

```
dictionary = {1: "Countries, Cities and Villages", 2: "Animals", 3: "Objects"}

for k, v in dictionary.items():
    print(k, v)
```

The difference between dictionary and dictionary.items() is the following

```
dictionary: {1: 'Countries, Cities and Villages', 2: 'Animals', 3: 'Objects'}
dictionary.items(): dict_items([(1, 'Countries, Cities and Villages'), (2, 'Animals'), (3, 'Objects')])
```

Using dictionary.items() we'll get a view object containig the key-value pairs of the dictionary, as tuples in a list. In other words, with dictionary.items() you'll also get a list of tuples. If you don't use it, you'll get

> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

If you want to get the same output using a simple list, you'll have to use something like enumerate()

```
list = ["Countries, Cities and Villages","Animals", "Objects"]

for k, v in enumerate(list, 1): # 1 means that I want to start from 1 instead of 0
    print(k, v)
```

If you don't, you'll get

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

So, this naturally raises the question... **do I need always a list of tuples?** No. Using enumerate() we'll get an enumerate object.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, "the simplest way of using a for loop an iterating over an array" (the Python type is named "list" BTW) is the second one, ie

```
for item in somelist:
    do_something_with(item)
```

which FWIW works for all iterables (lists, tuples, sets, dicts, iterators, generators etc).

The range-based C-style version is considered highly unpythonic, and will only work with lists or list-like iterables.

> What I would like to know is what this does

```
for i, j in range(len(array)):
    # What is i and j here?
```

Well, you could just test it by yourself... But the result is obvious: it will raise a `TypeError` because unpacking only works on iterables and ints are not iterable.

> or

```
for i, j in array:
    # What is i and j in this case?
```

Depends on what is `array` and what it yields when iterating over it. If it's a list of 2-tuples or an iterator yielding 2-tuples, `i` and `j` will be the elements of the current iteration item, ie:

```
array = [(letter, ord(letter)) for letter in "abcdef"]
for letter, letter_ord in array:
    print("{} : {}".format(letter, letter_ord))
```

Else, it will most probably raise a TypeError too.

Note that if you want to have both the item and index, the solution is the builtin `enumerate(sequence)`, which yields an `(index, item)` tuple for each item:

```
array = list("abcdef")
for index, letter in enumerate(array):
    print("{} : {}".format(index, letter)
```

Answer (score 2):

Understood your question, explaining it using a different example.

## 1. Multiple Assignments using -> Dictionary

```
dict1 = {1: "Bitcoin", 2: "Ethereum"}

for key, value in dict1.items():
    print(f"Key {key} has value {value}")

print(dict1.items())
```

**Output:**

```
Key 1 has value Bitcoin
Key 2 has value Ethereum
dict_items([(1, 'Bitcoin'), (2, 'Ethereum')])
```

**Explaining** `dict1.items()`:

> `dict1_items()` creates values `dict_items([(1, 'Bitcoin'), (2, 'Ethereum')])`

> It comes in pairs (key, value) for each iteration.

## 2. Multiple Assignments using -> enumerate() Function

```
coins = ["Bitcoin", "Ethereum", "Cardano"]
prices = [48000, 2585, 2]
for i, coin in enumerate(coins):
    price = prices[i]
    print(f"${price} for 1 {coin}")
```

**Output:**

```
$48000 for 1 Bitcoin
$2585 for 1 Ethereum
$2 for 1 Cardano
```

**Explaining** `enumerate(coins)`:

> `enumerate(coins)` creates values `((0, 'Bitcoin'), (1, 'Ethereum'), (2, 'Cardano'))`

> It comes in pairs (index, value) for each (one) iteration

## 3. Multiple Assignments using -> zip() Function

```
coins = ["Bitcoin", "Ethereum", "Cardano"]
prices = [48000, 2585, 2]
for coin, price in zip(coins, prices):
    print(f"${price} for 1 {coin}")
```

**Output:**

```
$48000 for 1 Bitcoin
$2585 for 1 Ethereum
$2 for 1 Cardano
```

**Explaining**

> `zip(coins, prices)` create values `(('Bitcoin', 48000), ('Ethereum', 2585), ('Cardano', 2))`

> It comes in pairs `(value-list1, value-list2)` for each (one) iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that, even in Python, you can get a `for in` effect using a classic C style loop by just using a local variable

```
l = len(mylist) #I often need to use this more than once anyways

for n in range(l-1):
    i = mylist[n]
    
    print("iterator:",n, " item:",i)
```